# Is there a way I can quickly find all faces using materials?

Tags: texturing, materials, faces

I have a mesh that has a variety of materials. With over 5,000 faces, manually searching for this face that has this material by clicking each face is difficult. Is it possible to find all faces with a single click on material?

Comment: In _Edit Mode_ make sure all faces are deselected by pressing `Alt` + `A` and then select the material you want to get the faces using it in the _Material Properties_. Below the material slots there is a _Select_ button. If you click it, all faces using this material will be selected.